# Simplifying linq when filtering data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wanted to ask for suggestions how I can simplify the foreach block below. I tried to make it all in one linq statement, but I couldn't figure out how to manipulate "count" values inside the query.

More details about what I'm trying to achieve:
- I have a huge list with potential duplicates, where Id's are repeated, but property "Count" is different numbers
- I want to get rid of duplicates, but still not to loose those "Count" values
- so for the items with the same Id I summ up the "Count" properties

Still, the current code doesn't look pretty:

```
var grouped = bigList.GroupBy(c => c.Id).ToList();
foreach (var items in grouped)
{
    var count = 0;
    items.Each(c=> count += c.Count);
    items.First().Count = count;
}
var filtered =  grouped.Select(y => y.First());
```

I don't expect the whole solution, pieces of ideas will be also highly appreciated :)

Comment: FWIW ReSharper is great at turning `foreach` code into equivalent LINQ statements.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919100/linq-groupby-count

Comment: definitely recommend trying resharper eval

Comment: You can probably do away with the .ToList() and just work with the IEnumerable returned; probably faster this way as enumeration is not forced by the .ToList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filtered = bigList.GroupBy(c=>c.Id)
                      .Select(g=> {
                                    var f = g.First();
                                    f.Count = g.Sum(c=>c.Count);
                                    return f;
                                  });
```

Comment: This is basically the equivalent to the original - but mutation of the original data during queries just seems wrong ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I was tempted to +1 KingKing's answer until I saw your comment. You might want to edit your answer to add a little more background information about why you chose to avoid mutating the collection.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce I did +1 this answer, but felt that I needed to comment, so it was at least known that this does cause mutation of the original data.

Comment: Also - realize this will have no effect unless you iterate through this (ie: use `foreach` or just add `ToList()` at the end)

Comment: @ReedCopsey of course,, I guess he may want to perform some `foreach` then such as to print out the info.

Comment: @ReedCopsey The OP showed in her code this `items.First().Count = count;` that means she understands that she wants to mutate it, I can understand the mutation here but that's what the OP wants. She even tried her code and just wanted to have a `LINQ version`.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I know - but I also refuse to propagate bad design if there's a simple alternative.  I still strongly believe that mutation within queries is just a very bad practice, and should be avoided.

Comment: About the mutation, those collections are temporary, so, I do not change original data by changing them. My only intention was to put all counts into the first item and remove others duplicates. I agree, that my approach wasn't good.

Comment: @KingKing noticed a bug in there - one of the values will be counted twice :)

Answer (score 5):

Given that you're mutating the collection, I would personally just make a new "item" with the count:

```
var results = bigList.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                     .Select(g => new Item(g.Key, g.Sum(i => i.Count)))
                     .ToList();
```

This performs a simple mapping from the original to a new collection of `Item` instances, with the proper `Id` and `Count` values.

Comment: I'm sorry but your `Item` may lack more info, such as the original one doesn't have only `Id` and `Count`, it may have more properties than that and the OP wants to include/keep all the properties? We can use the `constructor` to create a new instance of the original type but the OP doesn't show the original type, so it's stuck.

Comment: @KingKing Yes - and that would need to be added to the construction - you should always be able to copy that object via the constructor (or object initializer), though.

Comment: Looks good! But as @KingKing mentioned, you loose all the info about original data, which I still need.